# How to set div width to the width of the table in it?

Tags: html, css, width, css-tables

I have a `div`, which contains a `table`. Everything is working as I want, except I don't know how to set the `width` of the `div` so that it grows as the `width` of the `table` inside it grows. How Can I do that? Thanks.

This is the CSS code of the `div`:

```
#events-table-wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Setting `width` to `auto` didn't help. Btw, I didn't change anything in the table in CSS.

Edit: Here is a live version: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDF2U/

Comment: @user1136076 http://jsfiddle.net/ZDF2U/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case you can also do in the `div`:

```
display: table;
```

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/Et3t5/

---

Here's another jsFiddle that shows you a similar case: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/T7DTc/

If the div's `width: auto;` then it expands to accommodate the `textarea` inside the table. If you set it to `width: 500px;` then the `textarea` grows outside the div.

So the solution looks like setting `width: auto;`. Of course something special in your code may be interfering.

Comment: In that case the div has the width of the whole page.

Comment: Very nice solution. Better than setting table width to 100%. Thank!

Answer (score 2):

Setting `table { width:100% }` solved it. Now I can keep the `div` big enough and the table just fits in it. Thanks.

Comment: Leniel's solution is better. This one still requires you to mess with the width of the div.

Answer (score 1):

Make the div containing the table `inline-block`. I.e. `display: inline-block`. This will force it to render inline while being block. Alternatively `display: table` will work too.

Link to a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mr9jQ/

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the divs properties to be

```
float:left;
width:auto;
```